# What are the benefits of writing "functional" Javascript as opposed to OO?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I often come across Javascript code snippets that consist of many anonymous functions that are called where they are created, such as [here](https://code.downthemall.net/repos/trunk/modules/manager/preallocator/win.js):

```
var prealloc = (function() {
    // some definitions here

    return function prealloc_win(file, size, perms, sparseOk) {
        // function body
    };
})();
// can be called like this:
prealloc(...);
```

So this calls an anonymous function which returns another function `prealloc_win`. To me this seems equivalent to instantiating a class where the resulting object exposes the function `prealloc_win`:

```
function preallocObj() { 
    // some definitions here  
    this.prealloc_win = function(file, size, perms, sparseOk) {
        // function body
    }; 
}
prealloc = new preallocObj();
// can be called like this:
prealloc.prealloc_win(...);
```

Is this assumption correct? What are the benefits of using anonymous functions that are called directly? And why is this idiom so often seen in Javascript, but not often in other languages which could be written in the same way (C, C++, Python)?

Comment: The `//some definitions here` would all be dumped into global scope without the wrapping function

Comment: @Esailija Wouldn't you still have a wrapping function in Javascript's OOP model? Only that it's then used like a class ...

Comment: Can you show an example of what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Esailija I have updated the question to include an example.

Comment: I see. But there is no point in doing that since it's not something that will get instantiated multiple times. You are only gonna use the `new preallocObj()` once and it doesn't really fit that way.

Comment: @Esailija So considering runtime and other factors, it is equivalent, and the one true benefit is that the anonymous function, being anonymous, cannot be called more than once? Kind of like the "singleton" design pattern?

Comment: Yes, the deal is that there is no way to reference the anonymous function after it was invoked. So you cannot create more than one "instance" of it, and that "instance" was created right away and assigned to `prealloc`. With the class you gave, I could create more instances of it by using `new prealloc.constructor()` (Or just by direct reference: `new preallocObj()` in case it was exposed) even though it doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Esailija OK, got that, so it's basically Javascript's take on encapsulation and the singleton pattern. You could write this as an answer, the other two didn't really answer my question so I would accept yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deal is that the `preallocObj` class says that this is something that could be 
instantiated multiple times. I could just create more instances of it even though it wasn't really designed for that. You could do some hacks to prevent that but it's easier just to use the immediately invoked anonymous function for this.

With the immediately created and invoked anonymous function, a "class" is created, instantly "instantiated" and assigned to `prealloc` and
there is no way to reference the original anonymous function that created the `prealloc` object after this. It was created, invoked and lost.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much have the right idea. The benefits of this module pattern/function builder are that the resultant function can enclose its own internal definitions or state.

It's basically just a way to create a function with private variables or constants. Consider the less efficient alternative:

```
var prealloc = function() {
  // some definitions here
  // function body
}
```

Every time this function is called it would reassign/instantiate its variables, adding unnecessary performance overhead and overwriting any state data that resulted from previous calls.

This method is useful when there are some variables that are important to the workings of a function that you want only private access to or that you need to persist between invocations without contaminating the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is fundamentally very different to C++, JAVA and Python and should be written in differnt ways.  At the risk of repetition, Javascript is not an OOP language it is a prototype language.  [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/) (inventor of JSON) at Yahoo has some wonderful articles and particuarily Videos entitled 'Javascript - the good parts' you should watch them all.